# Can a White Court Vampire heal Hunger Stress with Inhuman Recovery?

Tags: fate, dresden-files, stress

Consider if a White Court Vampire uses *Inhuman Recovery*, *Quickness*, and *Might* in a scene. Used powers 2 + 2 + 2 = 6

At the end of the scene he makes a hunger check with his discipline 4. The dice show: **[0] [0] [+] [–]**. The result of this is 4 compared to 6 Attack Power Level, and they take 2 stress points for Hunger Stress.

Now the options are:

1. Take 2 stress points at Hunger Stress Track + directly lose 2 points in the refresh powers or
2. Take a mild Consequence (also worth 2 points)

But can this mild consequence of the hunger failure be healed by inhuman recovery?

I think it might be one of these cases:

1. A Mild Consequence can be healed immediately by "Inhuman Recovery", which in turn would result in a new Hunger Stress check against the power 2,
   or
2. Hunger Stress Consequences cannot be "healed" – the character has to feed one scene to regain this.

Comment: I've given your post a significant edit to clarify it. Could you please check if it's still consistent with what you're trying to ask, and if not, [edit] it further? I have also removed your last paragraph about feeding, as it appears to be a different matter that should be asked about separately -- but also I'm not sure if there's an actual question there I can recognise. You can still access that post by visiting your post's revision history via the [edited X time ago](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/101500/revisions) at the bottom of your post.

Answer (score 18):

Inhuman Recovery allows the recovery of a single *physical* mild consequence.

Feeding Dependency inflicts *hunger* consequences, not physical consequences.

The only way to restore those is going to be to either feed or make a successful discipline check so as to start recovery normally.